# How do I get the value of a JSON result into a label?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the result: [{"apn":"173-76-001"}]

From this code (php):

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
    $data = $db->get_results("select apn from parcels where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);
    if($data != null) echo json_encode($data);
    //if ($data != null) echo $data;
}
?>
```

jquery:

```
        $('#searchTable tr').click(function(){
            var parcel_id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(parcel_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: "classes/get-apn.php?id=" + parcel_id,
                //timeout: 30000,
                type: "GET",
                error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    //do stuff here on success
                    alert(data);
                    $('#ParcelNumber').val(data);               
                }
            });
        });
```

How do I get the value of apn (173-76-001) into a label??

Im new at all this so thanks for your help in advance!!! :)

EDIT: So I tried the response below but it didn't work. I was told I need to parse using jQuery.parsJSON but it's not working either. I'm so confused. Here's my updated jQuery code:

```
        $('#searchTable tr').click(function(){
            var parcel_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#ParcelId').html(parcel_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: "classes/get-apn.php?id=" + parcel_id,
                //timeout: 30000,
                type: "GET",
                data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    //do stuff here on success
                    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(result.apn);  
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perform the ajax request to the server. Server queries the DB and formats output as json. Ajax request hereby succeeded and the following line of code sets the label’s value:

```
$('#ParcelNumber').val(data);
```

Label ID here is `ParcelNumber`. To get the value you probably need to:

```
$('#ParcelNumber').val(data[0]["apn"]);
```

Whether `ParcelNumber` is not “valued” control (e.g. not an `input` but static div), use `.html` method:

```
$('#ParcelNumber').html(data[0]["apn"]);
```

Comment: I changed it to `$('#ParcelNumber').val(data["apn"]);` and now my page is broken :( 

Is [{"apn":"173-76-001"}] an array result? Looks weird like there are one too many brackets.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed there is an array. Please see updated answer. BTW, brackets there mean “array consisting of one element, element is apn=...”

Comment: I'll give that a try. I completely just broke my page and I have no idea how :(

Comment: AHHH!!!! I got it!!! Has to be `.html`! Works now with that: `$('#ParcelNumber').html(data[0]["apn"]);` TY TY!